# One of dataframe string index cannot be indexed while other can

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have this dataframe with string index

```py
                      1
Abai                  Abai.1
Native to             Indonesia
Region                Borneo
Language family       Austronesian
ISO 639-3             None (mis)
Glottolog             abai1241
```

Strangely when I try to access the "Native to" index using loc

```py
df.loc["Native to"]
```

it returns `KeyError`. But when I try to access "Language family" index using the same method, it works and returns the Series object.

```py
In [5]: df.loc["Language family"]
Out[5]:
1    Austronesian
Name: Language family, dtype: object
```

The same goes for other index with spaces in it, while other index without spaces just working fine.

After a little bit of investigation my suspicion points to the space character in the "Native to" string. The code block below would explain it.

```py
# I found that
df.loc[df.index.str.contains("Native")]

# returns this dataframe
#                     1
# Native to           Indonesia

# while the code below (notice the additional space)
df.loc[df.index.str.contains("Native ")]

# returns an empty Dataframe

# meanwhile this code (notice the same additional space)
df.loc[df.index.str.contains("Language ")]

# returns
#                     1
# Language family     Austronesian
```

May anyone point out what is the problem I am having here? Is this caused by the string itself or a bug in pandas or something?

**Edit**
Turns out it was not caused by trailing spaces as after `.strip()` method it's still produce the same error.

Comment: What is the output of `df.index.tolist()`? Double check for leading/trailing spaces

Comment: If I copy/paste your data from Edit, you have a tabulation after `Native to\t`.

Comment: @mozway ah yes it contains \xa0 unicode char, so its actually `Native\xa0to`. Not trailing spaces but different string encoding.

Comment: @Corralien maybe it's a copy/paste from a notebook, with tabulations the display should have been an obvious `Abai\t                   Abai.1`

Comment: Can you provide a reproducible input for the DataFrame?

Comment: @mozway the dataframe created by scraping the infobox of a wikipedia page, i use this code [here](https://gist.github.com/aculich/b34868c098d94d614515).

Answer (score 1):

You likely have dangling spaces. Cleanup your index with:

```
df.index = df.index.str.strip()
```